# Distribution of distances with two shifted vectors

Tags: probability

Let $A$ be a uniformly random vector of length $n$ where the entries are either $0$ or $1$. Let $B$ be a uniformly random vector of length $n+1$ where the entries are also either $0$ or $1$.  Now consider the random variable $X = \Delta(A,B[0,n-1]) - \Delta(A,B[1,n])$ where $\Delta$ just measures the Hamming distance between two vectors of the same length.

```
What is the distribution of X?
```

We can see immediately that $\mathbb{E}(X) = 0$.  Empirically it looks like it is normally distributed with variance $n/2$.  Below is a histogram using $10000$ samples and $n = 100$ with a normal distribution with variance $50$ drawn over it.

[image]

**EDIT.**  I would really like to know why or if the distribution converges to normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $Y$ be the number of transitions in entries of $B$ from $0$ to $1$ or from $1$ to $0$. Each such transition contributes 1 to one Hamming distance and 0 to the other Hamming distance.

First consider distribution of $Y$. In a random sequence, each new entry after first, is likely to be a transition with probability 0.5. So $Y=y$ with probability ${n \choose y}0.5^n$.

Now, $X$ is the number of transitions that contribute 1 to first Hamming distance minus the number of transitions that contribute 1 to the second Hamming distance.  So $X=x$ and $Y=y$ if there are $(y+x)/2$ transitions that contribute to first Hamming distance and $(y-x)/2$ transitions that contribute to the second Hamming distance. Since $A$ is random, each transition is equally likely to contribute to first or second Hamming distance. So conditional on $Y=y$, the probability that $X=x$ is ${y \choose (y+x)/2}0.5^y$. Relaxing condition on $y$, the probability that $X=x$ is

$\sum_{y=|x|}^{|x|+2\lfloor \frac{n-|x|}{2} \rfloor}{y \choose (y+x)/2}0.5^y{n \choose y}0.5^n \\ =\frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{y=|x|}^{|x|+2\lfloor \frac{n-|x|}{2} \rfloor} \left\{ \frac{n!}{2^y(n-y)!(\frac{y-x}{2})!(\frac{y+x}{2})!} \right\} \\
=\frac{n!}{2^{n+|x|}} \left\{ \frac{1}{4^{0}(n-|x|)!(|x|)!(0)!} + \frac{1}{4^{1}(n-|x|-2)!(|x|+1)!(1)!} + \frac{1}{4^{2}(n-|x|-4)!(|x|+2)!(2)!} + ... +  \frac{1}{4^{\lfloor \frac{n-|x|}{2} \rfloor}(n-|x|-2\lfloor \frac{n-|x|}{2} \rfloor)!(|x|+\lfloor \frac{n-|x|}{2} \rfloor)!(\lfloor \frac{n-|x|}{2} \rfloor)!}  \right\}.$

I am not sure if this can be simplified to a nice expression.

For convergence to normality, $X$ is a sum of $n$ random variables $z_1$ to $z_n$ where $z_i$ is 1 if $i$th bit of $A$ is same as $i$th bit of $B$ but differs from $(i+1)$th bit of $B$, -1 if $i$th bit of $A$ is same as $(i+1)$th bit of $B$ but differs from $i$th bit of $B$, and is $0$ otherwise. So $z_i$ has mean $0$ and variance $1/2$. And all $z_i$ are iid so $X$, the sum of all $z_i$ has mean $0$, variance $n/2$ and converges to a normal distribution by central limit theorem.

Comment: Thank you. To get the normal convergence I suppose the easiest route would somehow be to express $X$ as a sum of random variables. Do you think that can be done?